# Print / Find the first character (with the LOWEST occurrence) in a non-empty string and order is important

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, one-liner

**BASH** GNU bash, version **4.2.46**(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Given a string **str**, which can store only any lower, UPPER or number values only.

How can I find the first character (**with the LOWEST occurrence**) in a **non-empty** string `str`? The focus of the problem is to print letter '**z**' if the script is this (as fast as possible, without getting any errors if the data is in a string or a file): https://repl.it/@asangal/find1stleastoccurrencecharmaintainorderanyleastsize

**or Sample example** values of `str`:

`str=aa`, output should be '**a**'  (as 'a' is the only one char in string - occurred 2 times)

`str=aa1`, output should be '**1**' (as '1' is the first character with lowest occurrence count of 1)

`str=aa1c1deef`, output should be '**c**' (as 'c' came before 'd' and both had 1 as lowest occurrence count of 1)

`str=abcdeeddAbac`, output should be '**A**' (as 'A' is the first character with lower occurrence count of 1)

`str=abcdeeddAbacA`, output should be '**a**' (as 'a' is the first character with lower occurrence count of 2)

`str=abcdeeddAbacAabc`, output should be '**e**' (as 'e' is the first character with lower occurrence count of 2)

**Other large size example value** can be:

`str=axavzzzfdfdsldfnasdlkfjasdlkfjaslkfjasldkfjaslfjlasjkflasdkjfasdlfjasdljfasdkjfgio23yoryoiasyfoiywoerihlkdfhlaskdnkasdnvxcnvjzxkiivhaslyqwoyroiqwyroqwroqwlkasddlkkhaslkfjasdldkfjalsdkfashoqwiyroiqwyroiqwhrkjhajkdfhaslfkhasldkfh`, output should be '**g**' (as 'g' is the first character with lowest occurrence count of 1)

**Constraints / Context:**

1. **Value** can be a set of either a **lower**, **UPPER** or a **Number**
2. String will always be **non-empty**; we can ignore any space type characters  in the value for now.
3. Find the first letter(**[a-zA-Z0-9]**) present in the `str` string **with lowest occurrence count**.
4. If possible, I **don't want to use** any Statements (ex: if-then-else), loops (For/While) or user defined functions. *Use of commands, library functions* (if any available to a user out of the box) is **OK**.

**PS:** I know system level commands does call all these things behind the scene, but I'm looking for **minimal code** if possible **at command line** i.e. **$** prompt.

I tried the following ugly-looking **non-one-liner** attempt as listed below, *here I have the **for** loop **which I want to avoid** if possible* and the `sort` command is helping but also making me loose the order and doesn't cover all the conditions.

*I don't like my current attempt that I have listed below, but seems like I'm close.*

```
str="axavzzzfdfdsldfnasdlkfjasdlkfjaslkfjasldkfjaslfjlasjkflasdkjfasdlfjasdljfasdkjfgio23yoryoiasyfoiywoerihlkdfhlaskdnkasdnvxcnvjzxkiivhaslyqwoyroiqwyroqwroqwlkasddlkkhaslkfjasdldkfjalsdkfashoqwiyroiqwyroiqwhrkjhajkdfhaslfkhasldkfh";
for char in $(echo $str | sed "s/\(.\)/\1\n/g" | grep .| tr '\012' ' '); 
do
    echo -n "$char=$(echo ${str} | sed "s/\(.\)/\1\n/g" | grep . | grep -c $char)";echo;
done | sort -u
```

I believe it's possible to achieve what I'm looking for as a **One-liner** (i.e. by using bunch of common Linux commands and pipes **|**) in BASH; just wanted to pick your brain! I know there are better **shell** experts than me.

Most of the solutions I found online don't maintain the order (which is important to me) and just give the highest/lower occurrence/count of a character.

Comment: *One-liner*? This is not [codegolf.se].

Comment: @oguzismail thanks for pointing me to Code Golf, I'm poking into it now; hm.. didn't know about it.

Comment: @oguzismail this https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ is awesome! Thanks for sharing. It'll keep me happy.

Comment: Any command can be written as a "one-liner" but asking for a "one-liner" tells us you care more about brevity that you do about anything that actually matters in software, e.g. clarity, robustness, portability, efficiency, etc. so YMMV with getting people to help you and YMMV with how happy you'll be over time with the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWER #4 - file/substr()/reduced-array-usage solution**

After some back-n-forth with @AKS, and using an ever-larger data set (latest test using a 36 MB file), the `awk/array` memory issue has cropped up (eg, for the larger dataset the various `awk` answers - up to this point - require 6-8 GB of RAM).

My first attempt at addressing the memory issue will be to copy all of the input into a new variable; yeah, this means copying 36 MB of data into an `awk` variable, but that'll still be a lot less than 6-8 GB of RAM.

Using the new (bigger) dataset provided by @AKS:

```
$ str="upvouapouqweruuUPOUADUFUAUASDFLKHLPlakjfaldsfpuFHAOOJJADFIASYDOYsggdhuafaismxasidfuasudfoasdufoiasudfoiayioOISYDOIQYORIYOIRYOIYQNOIYFAclamscvjlaivniauppruporupourpoupupovupuadouaouuouaudfaodfpadufuudofupuaspfupipoporqwooPOFPUnmcupauvpaupvouapouqweruuUPOUADUFUAUASDFLKHLPlakjfaldsfpuFHAOOJJADFIASYDOYsggdhuafaismxasidfuasudfoasdufoiasudfoiayioOISYDOIQYORIYOIRYOIYQNOIYFAclamscvjlaivniauppruporupourpoupupovupuadouaouuouaudfaodfpadufuudofupuaspfupipoporqwooPOFPUnmcupauvpaupvouapouqweruuUPOUADUFUAUASDFLKHLPlakjfaldsfpuFHAOOJJADFIASYDOYsggdhuafaismxasidfuasudfoasdufoiasudfoiayioOISYDOIQYORIYOIRYOIYQNOIYFAclamscvjlaivniauppruporupourpoupupovupuadouaouuouaudfaodfpadufuudofupuaspfupipoporqwooPOFPUnmcupauvpaupvouapouqweruuUPOUADUFUAUASDFLKHLPlakjfaldsfpuFHAOOJJADFIASYDOYsggdhuafaismxasidfuasudfoasdufoiasudfoiayioOISYDOIQYORIYOIRYOIYQNOIYFAclamscvjlaivniauppruporupourpoupupovupuadouaouuouaudfaodfpadufuudofupuaspfupipoporqwooPOFPUnmcupauvpaupvouapouqweruuUPOUADUFUAUASDFLKHLPlakjfaldsfpuFHAOOJJADFIASYDOYsggdhuafaismxasidfuasudfoasdufoiasudfoiayioOISYDOIQYORIYOIRYOIYQNOIYFAclamscvjlaivniauppruporupourpoupupovupuadouaouuouaudfaodfpadufuudofupuaspfupipoporqwooPOFPUnmcupauvpaupvouapouqweruuUPOUADUFUAUASDFLKHLPlakjfaldsfpuFHAOOJJADFIASYDOYsggdhuafaismxasidfuasudfoasdufoiasudfoiayioOISYDOIQYORIYOIRYOIYQNOIYFAclamscvjlaivniauppruporupourpoupupovupuadouaouuouaudfaodfpadufuudofupuaspfupipoporqwooPOFPUnmcupauvpaupvouapouqweruuUPOUADUFUAUASDFLKHLPlakjfaldsfpuFHAOOJJADFIASYDOYsggdhuafaismxasidfuasudfoasdufoiasudfoiayioOISYDOIQYORIYOIRYOIYQNOIYFAclamscvjlaivniauppruporupourpoupupovupuadouaouuouaudfaodfpadufuudofupuaspfupipoporqwooPOFPUnmcupauvpaupvouapouqweruuUPOUADUFUAUASDFLKHLPlakjfaldsfpuFHAOOJJADFIASYDOYsggdhuafaismxasidfuasudfoasdufoiasudfoiayioOISYDOIQYORIYOIRYOIYQNOIYFAclamscvjlaivniauppruporupourpoupupovupuadouaouuouaudfaodfpadufuudofupuaspfupipoporqwooPOFPUnmcupauvpaupvouapouqweruuUPOUADUFUAUASDFLKHLPlakjfaldsfpuFHAOOJJADFIASYDOYsggdhuafaismxasidfuasudfoasdufoiasudfoiayioOISYDOIQYORIYOIRYOIYQNOIYFAclamscvjlaivniauppruporupourpoupupovupuadouaouuouaudfaodfpadufuudofupuaspfupipoporqwooPOFPUnmcupauvpaupvouapouqweruuUPOUADUFUAUASDFLKHLPlakjfaldsfpuFHAOOJJADFIASYDOYsggdhuafaismxasidfuasudfoasdufoiasudfoiayioOISYDOIQYORIYOIRYOIYQNOIYFAclamscvjlaivniauppruporupourpoupupovupuadouaouuouaudfaodfpadufuudofupuaspfupipoporqwooPOFPUnmcupauvpaupvouapouqweruuUPOUADUFUAUASDFLKHLPlakjfaldsfpuFHAOOJJADFIASYDOYsggdhuafaismxasidfuasudfoasdufoiasudfoiayioOISYDOIQYORIYOIRYOIYQNOIYFAclamscvjlaivniauppruporupourpoupupovupuadouaouuouaudfaodfpadufuudofupuaspfupipoporqwooPOFPUnmcupauvpaupvouapouqweruuUPOUADUFUAUASDFLKHLPlakjfaldsfpuFHAOOJJADFIASYDOYsggdhuafaismxasidfuasudfoasdufoiasudfoiayioOISYDOIQYORIYOIRYOIYQNOIYFAclamscvjlaivniauppruporupourpoupupovupuadouaouuouaudfaodfpadufuudofupuaspfupipoporqwooPOFPUnmcupauvpaupvouapouqweruuUPOUADUFUAUASDFLKHLPlakjfaldsfpuFHAOOJJADFIASYDOYsggdhuafaismxasidfuasudfoasdufoiasudfoiayioOISYDOIQYORIYOIRYOIYQNOIYFAclamscvjlaivniauppruporupourpoupupovupuadouaouuouaudfaodfpadufuudofupuaspfupipoporqwooPOFPUnmcupauvpaupvouapouqweruuUPOUADUFUAUASDFLKHLPlakjfaldsfpuFHAOOJJADFIASYDOYsggdhuafaismxasidfuasudfoasdufoiasudfoiayioOISYDOIQYORIYOIRYOIYQNOIYFAclamscvjlaivniauppruporupourpoupupovupuadouaouuouaudfaodfpadufuudofupuaspfupipoporqwooPOFPUnmcupauvpaupvouapouqweruuUPOUADUFUAUASDFLKHLPlakjfaldsfpuFHAOOJJADFIASYDOYsggdhuafaismxasidfuasudfoasdufoiasudfoiayioOISYDOIQYORIYOIRYOIYQNOIYFAclamscvjlaivniauppruporupourpoupupovupuadouaouuouaudfaodfpadufuudofupuaspfupipoporqwooPOFPUnmcupauvpaupvouapouqweruuUPOUADUFUAUASDFLKHLPlakjfaldsfpuFHAOOJJADFIASYDOYsggdhuafaismxasidfuasudfoasdufoiasudfoiayioOISYDOIQYORIYOIRYOIYQNOIYFAclamscvjlaivniauppruporupourpoupupovupuadouaouuouaudfaodfpadufuudofupuaspfupipoporqwooPOFPUnmcupauvpaupvouapouqweruuUPOUADUFUAUASDFLKHLPlakjfaldsfpuFHAOOJJADFIASYDOYsggdhuafaismxasidfuasudfoasdufoiasudfoiayioOISYDOIQYORIYOIRYOIYQNOIYFAclamscvjlaivniauppruporupourpoupupovupuadouaouuouaudfaodfpadufuudofupuaspfupipoporqwooPOFPUnmcupauvpaupvouapouqweruuUPOUADUFUAUASDFLKHLPlakjfaldsfpuFHAOOJJADFIASYDOYsggdhuafaismxasidfuasudfoasdufoiasudfoiayioOISYDOIQYORIYOIRYOIYQNOIYFAclamscvjlaivniauppruporupourpoupupovupuadouaouuouaudfaodfpadufuudofupuaspfupipoporqwooPOFPUnmcupauvpaupvouapouqweruuUPOUADUFUAUASDFLKHLPlakjfaldsfpuFHAOOJJADFIASYDOYsggdhuafaismxasidfuasudfoasdufoiasudfoiayioOISYDOIQYORIYOIRYOIYQNOIYFAclamscvjlaivniauppruporupourpoupupovupuadouaouuouaudfaodfpadufuudofupuaspfupipoporqwooPOFPUnmcupauvpaupvouapouqweruuUPOUADUFUAUASDFLKHLP"
$ for i in {1..10}; do str="${str}${str}"; done
$ for i in {1..3}; do str="${str}${str}"; done
$ echo -e "\n\n-- Adding 'z' the only char in this big string blob 'str' variable'\n"
$ str="${str}z"
$ echo $str | wc
      1       1 36864002
$ echo "${str}" > newgiga.txt
$ ls -lh newgiga.txt
-rw-r--r--+ 1 xxxxx yyyyy 36M Jun  6 16:55 newgiga.txt
```

**NOTE**: The way this data has been created, all letters/numbers occur more than once except for the letter `z` (which appears just once, and at the end of the entire dataset).

And the new/improved `awk` solution:

```
$ time awk '
{ copy = copy $0                                 # make a copy of our input for later reparsing
  len = length($0)

  for ( i=1; i<=len; i++ ) {                     # get a count of occurrences of each letter/number
      token = substr($0,i,1)
      count[token]++
  }
}

END { for ( i in count ) {
          if ( min <= 0 ) 
              min = count[i]
          else
              min = count[i]<min?count[i]:min    # find the lowest/minimum count
      }

      for ( i=1; i<=len; i++ ) {                 # reparse input looking for first letter with count == min
          token = substr(copy,i,1)
          if ( min == count[token] ) {
              print token, min                   # print the letter/number and count and
              break                              # break out of our loop
          }
      }
    }
' newgiga.txt

z 1                                              # as mentioned in the above NOTE => z occurs just once in the dataset

real    0m19.575s                                # slightly better rate than the previous answer #3 that took 6 secs for 14 MB of data
user    0m19.406s
sys     0m0.171s
```

**NOTE**: This answer used up 160 MB of memory on my machine (much better than the 6-8 GB of earlier answers) while also running at about the same rate as before.

---

Tried a solution that eliminates the `copy` variable and instead processes the input file a second time.  Results:

- total memory usage dropped by ~30 MB (to ~130 MB)
- total run time increased by ~2 seconds

So, the trade-offs aren't really worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks. Do we need to bump `min=10000000` to higher? seems like it's going to catch only 10million letters only and ignoring 38-40million+ letters?

Also, I ran the script on 2 of my EC2 machines. One with 4GB total RAM and other with 15GB total RAM. Here are the results. On 4GB, Ravinder's awk failed in 11seconds. Your solution 3rd is still running and no output so far for last 30 minutes but it's running, 100% CPU usage. On 4GB, my solution took 8 minutes. NOW, on 15GB, Ravinder script is hanging so far (got `Connection closed by remote host) so never reached your 3rd solution

Comment: On 15GB RAM machine EC2, I ran my solution, took 1 minute only for both solutions using str or file.
I'm running your new improved solution you posted on this answer now - on 15GB machine now to see if it reaps something really cool! So, far it shows me, that it's still running for last 6 minutes and no output.

Comment: this latest answer (#4) took ~90 seconds on that web/link you provided (in another comment) ... which is about right since it's probably a) a slower machine and/or b) runs scripts at a reduced priority; that doesn't sound right (6 min) ... its taking 18-20 secs on my VM (using ~160 MB of a max 8 GB of RAM)

Comment: Hm.. strange, on my EC2, my file shows the same byte size and I ran the 4th solution and it didn't output anything and finally got `connection got closed by remote host" and I came back to the machine from where I manually ssh'd to the new 15GB machine. I'll test more next week. For now, I'll upvote your answer as it's better solution than your other 3 solutions.

Comment: not sure what to say ... resource limits on EC2? *shrug*  I've cut-n-pasted the above into both a) my local VM and b) that web/link you referenced ... both return back with `z 1` in 18-20 secs and 90 secs, respectively

Comment: So, I tested on repl website on whatever resource machine they had and I think your solution beat all of us. Ravinder's failed in awk (i think your solution and his were same) and your first 3 solutions didn't work. Your 4th solution with improved file/substr()/non-array thing FINALLY WORKED and took only 1minute + and my solution on repl website took less than 8 minutes (one-liner kind of) but on 15GB machine mine took close to 1 minute. Marking your solution as the final answer! One interesting fact: On EC2 machine, when I ran 4th solution, it didn't spit anything for 8+ minutes FYI

Answer (score 4):

***EDIT2:*** In case anyone needs to know minimum value first appeared character/integer etc from whole Input_file then try following.

```
awk '
{
  num=split($0,array,"")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    ++count[array[i]]
  }
  for(j=1;j<=num;j++){
    tot_ind[count[array[j]]]=(tot_ind[count[array[j]]]?tot_ind[count[array[j]]] OFS:"")array[j]
  }
  for(i in count){
    min=min<=count[i]?(min?min:count[i]):count[i]
  }
}    
END{
  print "Minimum value found is:" min
  split(tot_ind[min],actual," ")
  print "All item(s) with same minimum values are:" actual[1]
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Since OP is getting an error so in spite of reading from a variable lets read from an Input_file, in case OP reading values from Input_file then try following.

```
awk '
{
  delete tot_ind
  delete array
  delete count
  delete actual
  min=""
  num=split($0,array,"")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    ++count[array[i]]
  }
  for(j=1;j<=num;j++){
    tot_ind[count[array[j]]]=(tot_ind[count[array[j]]]?tot_ind[count[array[j]]] OFS:"")array[j]
  }
  for(i in count){
    min=min<=count[i]?(min?min:count[i]):count[i]
  }
  print "Minimum value found is:" min
  split(tot_ind[min],actual," ")
  print "All item(s) with same minimum values are:" actual[1]
}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                                            ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  num=split($0,array,"")                                         ##Splitting current line into arrray with NULL delimiter.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){                                           ##Running loop to run till num here.
    ++count[array[i]]                                            ##Creating count array with index of valueof array and keep incrementing its value with 1.
  }
  for(j=1;j<=num;j++){                                           ##Running for loop till num here.
    tot_ind[count[array[j]]]=(tot_ind[count[array[j]]]?tot_ind[count[array[j]]] OFS:"")array[j]   ##Creating tot_ind with index of value of count array, this will have all values of minimum number here.
  }
  for(i in count){                                               ##Traversing in array count here.
    min=min<=count[i]?(min?min:count[i]):count[i]                ##Looking to get minimum value by comparing its value to each element.
  }
  print "Minimum value found is:" min                            ##Printing Minimum value here.
  split(tot_ind[min],actual," ")                                 ##Splitting tot_ind into actual array to get very first element of minimum value out of all values which have same minimum number.
  print "All item(s) with same minimum values are:" actual[1]    ##Printing very first minimum number here.
}' Input_file                                                    ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

To get very first minimum value which is occurring in Input_file(BTW by this solution all items which have same minimum values could be printed too, with minor change in this code's last print statement). Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
str="abcdeeddAbacA"
awk -v str="$str" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(str,array,"")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    ++count[array[i]]
  }
  for(j=1;j<=num;j++){
    tot_ind[count[array[j]]]=(tot_ind[count[array[j]]]?tot_ind[count[array[j]]] OFS:"")array[j]
  }
  for(i in count){
    min=min<=count[i]?(min?min:count[i]):count[i]
  }
    print "Minimum value found is:" min
    split(tot_ind[min],actual," ")
    print "All item(s) with same minimum values are:" actual[1]
}'
```

***PROOF of concept:*** Ran above with OP's examples.

```
./script.ksh aa
Minimum value found is:2
All item(s) with same minimum values are:a

./script.ksh aa1
Minimum value found is:1
All item(s) with same minimum values are:1

./script.ksh aa1c1deef
Minimum value found is:1
All item(s) with same minimum values are:c

./script.ksh abcdeeddAbac
Minimum value found is:1
All item(s) with same minimum values are:A

./script.ksh abcdeeddAbacA
Minimum value found is:2
All item(s) with same minimum values are:a

./script.ksh abcdeeddAbacAabc
Minimum value found is:2
All item(s) with same minimum values are:e
```

***NOTE:*** I saved above solution in a script file and passing OP's sample inputs as argument to script, OP could use in whatever way he wants, this was done to show how its working.

Answer (score 3):

**ANSWER #1 - string/variable based solution**

Assuming the desired string is stored in a variable `str`, here's one `awk` solution:

```
awk -v str="${str}" '
BEGIN { num = split(str,token,"")                # split str into an array of single letter/number elements

        for ( i=1; i<=num; i++ ) {               # get a count of occurrences of each letter/number
            count[token[i]]++
        }

        min = 10000000

        for ( i in count ) {
            min = count[i]<min?count[i]:min      # keep track of the lowest/minimum count
        }

        for ( i=1; i<=num; i++ ) {               # loop through array of letter/numbers
            if ( min == count[token[i]] ) {      # for the first letter/number we find where count = min
                print token[i], min              # print the letter/number and count and 
                break                            # then break out of our loop
            }
        }
      }'
```

Running the above against the different sample strings:

```
++++++++++++++++ str = aa
a 2
++++++++++++++++ str = aa1
1 1
++++++++++++++++ str = aa1c1deef
c 1
++++++++++++++++ str = abcdeeddAbac
A 1
++++++++++++++++ str = abcdeeddAbacA
a 2
++++++++++++++++ str = abcdeeddAbacAabc
e 2
++++++++++++++++ str = axavzzzfdfdsldfnasdlkfjasdlkfjaslkfjasldkfjaslfjlasjkflasdkjfasdlfjasdljfasdkjfgio23yoryoiasyfoiywoerihlkdfhlaskdnkasdnvxcnvjzxkiivhaslyqwoyroiqwyroqwroqwlkasddlkkhaslkfjasdldkfjalsdkfashoqwiyroiqwyroiqwhrkjhajkdfhaslfkhasldkfh
g 1
```

---

**ANSWER #2 - file/array based solution**

Looking at a comment OP made to RavinderSingh13's answer re: a really large string resides in a file, and assuming that file's name is `giga.txt` ...

We should be able to make some minor mods to the previous `awk` solution like such:

```
awk '
BEGIN { RS = "\0" }                            # address files with no cr/lf
{ num = split($0,token,"")                     # split line/$0 into an array of single letter/number elements

  for( i=1; i<=num; i++ ) {                    # get a count of occurrences of each letter/number
      all[NR i] = token[i]                     # token array is for current line/$0 while all array is for entire file
      count[token[i]]++
  }
}

END { min = 10000000

      for ( i in count ) {
          min = count[i]<min?count[i]:min      # find the lowest/minimum count
      }

      for ( i in all ) {                       # loop through array of letter/numbers
          if ( min == count[all[i]] ) {        # for the first letter/number we find where count = min
              print all[i], min                # print the letter/number and count and 
              break                            # then break out of our loop
          }
      }
    }
' giga.txt
```

Placing the longer `str` sample into `giga.txt`:

```
$ cat giga.txt
axavzzzfdfdsldfnasdlkfjasdlkfjaslkfjasldkfjaslfjlasjkflasdkjfasdlfjasdljfasdkjfgio23yoryoiasyfoiywoerihlkdfhlaskdnkasdnvxcnvjzxkiivhaslyqwoyroiqwyroqwroqwlkasddlkkhaslkfjasdldkfjalsdkfashoqwiyroiqwyroiqwhrkjhajkdfhaslfkhasldkfh
```

Running the above `awk` solution against `giga.txt` gives us:

```
$ awk '....' giga.txt
g 1
```

---

**ANSWER #3 - file/substr() based solution**

OP provided additional details on how to generate a 'large' file of data:

```
$ ls lR / > giga.txt       # I hit ^C after ~20 secs
$ sed  "s/\(.\)/\1\n/g" giga.txt | grep -o [a-zA-Z0-9] | tr -d '\012' > newgiga.txt       # remove all but letters and numbers
```

This gave me a 14 million character file (`newgiga.txt`).

I ran several timing tests, along with a new `awk` solution (see below), against the 14 million character file and came up with the following timings:

- 15 secs with **file/array** based `awk` solution (see my previous answer - above)
- 25 secs with OPs `sed/grep/echo/uniq/tr/sort` answer
- 4+ mins with RavinderSingh13's `awk` solution (actually hit ^C after 4 mins)
- **6 secs** with a new **file/substr()** based `awk` solution (see below)

**NOTE**: For all solutions run against my particular `newgiga.txt` file the final answer was the letter `Z` (with 365 occurrences).

By replacing the `split/array` code with a series of `substr()` calls, and making a small change to how the `all` array is indexed, I was able to cut ~60% off the run time of the previous **file/array** based `awk` solution:

```
awk '
BEGIN { RS = "\0" }
{ len=length($0)

  for( i=1; i<=len; i++ ) {                    # get a count of occurrences of each letter/number
      token=substr($0,i,1)
      a++
      all[a] = token                           # token array is for current line/$0 while all array is for entire file
      count[token]++
  }
}

END { min=10000000

      for( i in count ) {
          min = count[i]<min?count[i]:min      # find the lowest/minimum count
      }

      for( i in all ) {                        # loop through array of letter/numbers
          if ( min == count[all[i]] ) {        # for the first letter/number we find where count = min
              print all[i], min                # print the letter/number and count and
              break                            # break out of our loop
          }
      }
    }
' newgiga.txt
```

**NOTE**: To be honest I didn't expect the `substr()` calls to be faster than the `split/array` method but I'm guessing `awk` has a pretty fast builtin method for running `substr()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
grep -o . <<<  ${str} |  cat -n | sort -k2  | uniq -c -f1 |  sort -nr -k1 -k2 | sed 's/.*[ \t]//g;$!d'
```

Demo:

```
$str=aa
$grep -o . <<<  ${str} |  cat -n | sort -k2  | uniq -c -f1 |  sort -nr -k1 -k2 | sed 's/.*[ \t]//g;$!d' 
a
$str=aa1
$grep -o . <<<  ${str} |  cat -n | sort -k2  | uniq -c -f1 |  sort -nr -k1 -k2 | sed 's/.*[ \t]//g;$!d' 
1
$str=aa1c1deef
$grep -o . <<<  ${str} |  cat -n | sort -k2  | uniq -c -f1 |  sort -nr -k1 -k2 | sed 's/.*[ \t]//g;$!d' 
c
$str=abcdeeddAbac
$grep -o . <<<  ${str} |  cat -n | sort -k2  | uniq -c -f1 |  sort -nr -k1 -k2 | sed 's/.*[ \t]//g;$!d' 
A
$str=abcdeeddAbacA
$grep -o . <<<  ${str} |  cat -n | sort -k2  | uniq -c -f1 |  sort -nr -k1 -k2 | sed 's/.*[ \t]//g;$!d' 
e
$str=abcdeeddAbacAabc
$grep -o . <<<  ${str} |  cat -n | sort -k2  | uniq -c -f1 |  sort -nr -k1 -k2 | sed 's/.*[ \t]//g;$!d' 
e
$str=axavzzzfdfdsldfnasdlkfjasdlkfjaslkfjasldkfjaslfjlasjkflasdkjfasdlfjasdljfasdkjfgio23yoryoiasyfoiywoerihlkdfhlaskdnkasdnvxcnvjzxkiivhaslyqwoyroiqwyroqwroqwlkasddlkkhaslkfjasdldkfjalsdkfashoqwiyroiqwyroiqwhrkjhajkdfhaslfkhasldkf
$grep -o . <<<  ${str} |  cat -n | sort -k2  | uniq -c -f1 |  sort -nr -k1 -k2 | sed 's/.*[ \t]//g;$!d' 
g
$
```

Edit: In the below case

> str=abcdeeddAbacA, output should be 'a' (as 'a' is the first character
>   with lower occurrence count of 2)

`ee` is coming before `a`

Comment: I'm looking into this. `str=abcdeeddAbacA` should return `a` (as `a`, `e`, `c` and `A` are count 2 but `a` comes first so), it should not give `e`.

Comment: So, this solution is facing the issue of using `sort` (which helped with counting a given character using `uniq`) but in doing so, if there are more than one character with same count, it's lossing it's original order and only picking the LAST row. It's better than my original attempt for sure!

Comment: Digvijay FYI - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62232603/1499296

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I got it finally (ate 3 carrot pudding bowls 5'am onwards); I got motivated!! by you all.

- **No** `for` loops or `if-then` conditionals used.
- **No** variable creation during the operation.
- Using `time` before the following solution - shows it completed on the largest file I had under **1.5** seconds`real    0m1.428s`; while the `awk` solution using file, took around **4.5** seconds).
- Seems more like a **one-liner** (use of just `Linux commands` and `|` pipes).

Any comments are welcome (if I missed any use-case).

```
$ echo $str | egrep -o . | \
  egrep $(echo $str | grep -o [a-zA-Z0-9] | sort | uniq -c | \
    grep " $(echo $str | grep -o [a-zA-Z0-9] | sort | uniq -c| sort -n -k1 | head -1 | grep -ow " [0-9][0-9]*") " | \
  sed "s/^[ \t][ \t]*//"|cut -d' ' -f2 | tr '\012' '|' | sed "s/.$//") | head -1
```

It'll output the **letter(alnum)** only.

If one wants to see the count (kind of out of scope), they can change `-f2` to `-f1` in the cut command above.

Here's the script: https://repl.it/@asangal/find1stleastoccurrencecharmaintainorderanyleastsize

Comment: fwiw, my 2nd `awk` solution runs a tad bit faster than the one-liner (1.186 sec vs 1.482 secs) and outputs a single line (letter and count) as opposed to the one-liner that puts out XX lines for the letter of interest; for my `newgiga.txt` file - 1 million letters/numbers - the `awk` solution outputs `Z 19` while the one-liner outputs 19 lines of `Z`

Comment: ... and this one-liner is a bit confusing (to say the least) in trying to figure out what it's trying to accomplish (goes back to Ed Morton's comment (paraphrased) about lack of clarity); hope no one else will have to maintain this code ... weeks/months/years from now! :-)

Comment: ... and 17 (18?) sub-processes?

Comment: take a look at my 3rd answer; using a 14 million character file I ran some timings ... your answer, RavinderSingh13's answer, my file/array answer (answer #2) and a new file/substr() answer (answer #3) ... w/ the latter coming in quite a bit faster than the other 3

Comment: @markp-fuso Interesting and nice explanation. Thanks.

Comment: so I found the results different than what you mentioned above. I'm hoping I'm not missing anything. Anyways, here: https://repl.it/@asangal/find1stleastoccurrencecharmaintainorderanyleastsize

With Ravinder and your solutions (2nd and 3rd), awk barfed due to some reason.

Mine is slow (took 1 minute or so for 40Million characters or so) but output was correct (just one letter) and in this script (in the URL above), the output must be 'z' (as that's the only 1 in the final big blog. The script shows everything. Have a look at it. Thanks for coming up with all the findings.

Comment: Using that link ... the `awk` solutions were auto-killed by the host process (testing on my host shows all `awk` solutions using 6-8 GB of RAM so I'm guessing that web/link has some memory limits); your first solution took 10 minutes (at the web/link) to come back with the single z, while it took 55 seconds on my host; I knew the array solution would require a good bit of memory but I didn't give that enough thought re: size of input; this has been a good test; I've got a couple new solutions that eliminate the array (and excessive memory) usage and still run fast(er) ... working on new answer

Comment: I think you are right, on my side, it took 8 minutes or so for my solution (repl site). Now I'm running the script on a real ec2 machine. Ravinder's script failed with something like: `./find_1st_least_occurrence_letter_any_least_size.sh: line 43:  6134 Killed                  awk '` and

Comment: When it hits your 3rd solution for `awk`, I see that it's running for more than 15 minutes and `top` showing: `PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND` showing me `6144 giga_user  20   0  424632 236620   1004 R  99.7  6.1   0:06.04 awk` (taking 100% CPU) and `ps -eAf|grep awk` shows: `00:15:36 awk  BEGIN { RS = "\0" } { ....` and still continuing (no output so far). Did I miss anything? I really like your / Ravinder's solution if they work!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215445/discussion-between-markp-fuso-and-aks).

Answer (score 0):

If file fits in memory:

```
<file tr -dc '[:alnum:]' | perl -ln0777e 'while (($c=substr $_,0,1) ne q{}) {$n=eval "y/\Q$c\E//d"; $count{$n}=$count{$n}.$c} END{for (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %count) {print substr $count{$_},0,1; exit}}'
```